# Deploy existing Ionic / Firebase project to new Firebase hosting project

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4, firebase-cli

I have Ionic project which I have deploy to my Firebase project [**Project A**] hosting.

I need to deploy this same project to a new Firebase project [**Project B**] hosting.

I have edited all the required config values in

`environment.ts` , `environment.prod.ts`, `firebaserc`, `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

Did `ionic build --prod` and `firebase deploy`.

If I do `firebase init`, it says:

> .firebaserc already has a default project, using **project-B**.

I writing configuration info to firebase.json...

I writing project information to .firebaserc...

```
+  Firebase initialization complete!
```

But it always gives back the link of the old project [**Project A**].

```
+  Deploy complete!
**Hosting URL:** https://**Project-A**.web.app
```

What do I need to do so it can be hosted in my new Firebase project?